# Write the output in the same line of a file with Python

Tags: python-2.7, output

I'm trying to write the ouput from  list in the same line of a .txt file,so if my lists are a=[1,2,3] and b=[3,4,5]. I would like to have a .txt file like this:
1,2,3
3,4,5
Instead of this:
1
2
3
3
...
I would like to do somthing like:

```
for i in a:print i,
```

with the ",", but with output.write(i), it doesn't works. How can I do that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691311/python-how-to-write-multiple-strings-in-one-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting it in a string before writing it

```
w=""
for i in a:
   w+=i+" "
output.write(w)
```

This writes everything in a single line

Answer (score 0):

```
output.write(','.join(map(str,i)))
```