# Trying to figure out syntax for a .write() statement

Tags: python

First post to the forum here.  I searched for an answer, but wasnt exactly sure how to phrase the search.  I am currently working through "learn python the hard way" and one of the drills he uses this coding:

```
target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")
```

and my objective is to fit everything into calling target.write() one time rather than six, which i tried to do like this:

```
target.write(line1, "\n", line2, "\n", line3)
```

but i get an error for giving 5 arguments rather than 1. can anyone tell me the correct syntax?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691311/python-how-to-write-multiple-strings-in-one-line

Comment: **PLEASE** don't continue with Learn Python the Hard Way. It [really sucks](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints). There are many other resources out there, just search. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not the place to ask for recommendations or tutorials, but sites like Quora and Reddit should have good answers for you. I really like [*Learning Python*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do) by Mark Lutz.

Comment: i am currently reading that as well =) anyway thanks for the info, i was getting that feeling myself a bit, it isnt very interactive to just give you the code in each exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Using a comma sends each object as a separate argument. Concatenate them with `+` instead, or `join()` them:

```
target.write(line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3)
```

Or:

```
target.write('\n'.join((line1, line2, line3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's `str` `format`:

```
target.write('{}\n{}\n{}'.format(line1, line2, line3))
```